# SQL result to JSON as fast as possible

Tags: json, go, goroutine

I'm trying to transform the Go built-in sql result to JSON. I'm using goroutines for that but I got problems.

**The base problem:**

There is a really big database with around 200k user and I have to serve them through tcp sockets in a microservice based system. To get the users from the database spent 20ms but transform this bunch of data to JSON spend 10 seconds with the current solution. This is why I want to use goroutines.

**Solution with Goroutines:**

```
func getJSON(rows *sql.Rows, cnf configure.Config) ([]byte, error) {
    log := logan.Log{
        Cnf: cnf,
    }

    cols, _ := rows.Columns()

    defer rows.Close()

    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for result := range resultChannel {
            results = append(
                results,
                result,
            )
        }
    }()

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for rows.Next() {
            wg.Add(1)
            go handleSQLRow(cols, rows)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        defer close(resultChannel)
    }()

    <-done

    s, err := json.Marshal(results)
    results = []resultContainer{}
    if err != nil {
        log.Context(1).Error(err)
    }
    rows.Close()
    return s, nil
}

func handleSQLRow(cols []string, rows *sql.Rows) {
    defer wg.Done()
    result := make(map[string]string, len(cols))
    fmt.Println("asd -> " + strconv.Itoa(counter))
    counter++
    rawResult := make([][]byte, len(cols))
    dest := make([]interface{}, len(cols))

    for i := range rawResult {
        dest[i] = &rawResult[i]
    }
    rows.Scan(dest...) // GET PANIC
    for i, raw := range rawResult {
        if raw == nil {
            result[cols[i]] = ""
        } else {
            fmt.Println(string(raw))
            result[cols[i]] = string(raw)
        }
    }
    resultChannel <- result
}
```

This solution give me a panic with the following message:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x45974c]

goroutine 408 [running]:
panic(0x7ca140, 0xc420010150)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
database/sql.convertAssign(0x793960, 0xc420529210, 0x7a5240, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/database/sql/convert.go:88 +0x1ef1
database/sql.(*Rows).Scan(0xc4203e4060, 0xc42021fb00, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44)
    /usr/lib/golang/src/database/sql/sql.go:1850 +0xc2
github.com/PumpkinSeed/zerodb/operations.handleSQLRow(0xc420402000, 0x44, 0x44, 0xc4203e4060)
    /home/loow/gopath/src/github.com/PumpkinSeed/zerodb/operations/operations.go:290 +0x19c
created by github.com/PumpkinSeed/zerodb/operations.getJSON.func2
    /home/loow/gopath/src/github.com/PumpkinSeed/zerodb/operations/operations.go:258 +0x91
exit status 2
```

**The current solution which is working but spend too much time:**

```
func getJSON(rows *sql.Rows, cnf configure.Config) ([]byte, error) {
    log := logan.Log{
        Cnf: cnf,
    }
    var results []resultContainer
    cols, _ := rows.Columns()
    rawResult := make([][]byte, len(cols))
    dest := make([]interface{}, len(cols))

    for i := range rawResult {
        dest[i] = &rawResult[i]
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {

        result := make(map[string]string, len(cols))
        rows.Scan(dest...)
        for i, raw := range rawResult {
            if raw == nil {

                result[cols[i]] = ""

            } else {
                result[cols[i]] = string(raw)
            }
        }

        results = append(results, result)
    }
    s, err := json.Marshal(results)
    if err != nil {
        log.Context(1).Error(err)
    }
    rows.Close()
    return s, nil
}
```

**Question:**

Why the goroutine solution give me an error, where it is not an obvious panic, because the first ~200 goroutine running properly?!

**UPDATE**

Performance test for the original working solution:

```
INFO[0020] setup taken -> 3.149124658s                   file=operations.go func=operations.getJSON line=260 service="Database manager" ts="2017-04-02 19:45:27.132881211 +0100 BST"
INFO[0025] toJSON taken -> 5.317647046s                  file=operations.go func=operations.getJSON line=263 service="Database manager" ts="2017-04-02 19:45:32.450551417 +0100 BST"
```

The sql to map is 3 sec and to json is 5 sec.

Comment: The bottleneck, somewhat unsurprisingly, is json.Marshal.  There are a few other 3rd party libraries out there that claim to be faster handling JSON data.  Are you strictly required to use JSON?

Comment: See if your db will do the conversion for you. Postgres definitely will, ZeroDB seems to accept JSON queries but I'm not sure what the response format is.

Comment: @tier1 it is the early version of this project so I'm ready to hear your advice instead of JSON.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring What do you mean my DB do this? On DB level or on programing language level?

Comment: In Postgres you can use functions like [to_json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to format your SQL query results as JSON. This allows you to send it straight to the caller without having to marshal it in your application code.

Comment: Using JSON in an SQL database only makes sense in certain instances. People underestimate how slow it is to work with strings instead of better suited concrete types. I suggest you reformat your data.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring unfortunately I'm using MySQL which isn't support it.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, we have a symfony app where the data is coming from, impossible to reformat it. So we are talking about existing data.

Comment: In that case, it might be necessary to duplicate the data in a more speed friendly format. Keep doing whatever your other app requires, but duplicate all the current data, and any new data added, in standard DB types so that this current project is able to function properly. We don't know what your data looks like, so we don't know how difficult that might be, but it might be the best option. I'm doing something similar in a project I'm working on to speed up certain API calls and queries.

Comment: It looks like MySQL 5.7(+?) has [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html) support.

Comment: You might find this useful.  It's a list of serialization benchmarks in Go.  https://github.com/alecthomas/go_serialization_benchmarks

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I think it's really hard to do, because in this case have to syncronize the both database model in realtime. But it's not too easy to migrate, becuase there is a big monolitic app which is not too good for that.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring I tryed it out, but unfortunately it is not what I want they just provide JSON as a datatype. MySQL no supported JSON response yet.

Comment: @tier1 Thanx, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go routines won't improve performance on CPU-bound operations like JSON marshaling. What you need is a more efficient JSON marshaler. There are some available, although I haven't used any.  A simple Google search for 'faster JSON marshaling' will turn up many results. A popular one is [ffjson](https://github.com/pquerna/ffjson).  I suggest starting there.

Comment: Updated the post, and you are right the JSON marshal takes too much time, but I tryed the ffjson and I got the same numbers.